# My delete function is not removing entries and is being ignored

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am having problems getting my delete function to work in my ASP.net (C#) web application and I really have no idea where to go next.

The function is called on button clicked but it is as if the `Page_Load` method is completely ignoring the command. I'm new to this and would appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Here is the `Page_load`, the `DisplayData` method, the `Count` method and the `delete` method which is called from a button click.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    static int count = 1;
    static int max = 2;
    static String sqlQuery = "Select * from Footballer";
    static bool firstTime = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\App_Data\\Database2.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
        cn = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlCommand command = cn.CreateCommand();

        cn.Open();
        mycount();

        if (firstTime == true)
        {
            displayData();
           firstTime = false;
        }
    }

    protected void mycount()
    {   // count no of els in table
        max = 0;
        var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read()) max++;
        reader.Close();
    }

    protected void displayData()
    {
        var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
            reader.Read();

        TextBox1.Text = "" + reader[0];
        TextBox2.Text = "" + reader[1];
        TextBox5.Text = "" + reader[2];
        TextBox6.Text = "" + reader[3];
        TextBox7.Text = "" + reader[4];
        TextBox8.Text = "" + reader[5];

        reader.Close();
    }

    protected void deleteData()
    {
        var cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        string query = "DELETE FROM [Footballer] WHERE [PlayerName] = @name";
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        string name = TextBox4.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the deleteData() method, is it being hit?

Comment: Hi there Evan, Yes I tried that just there now and it's hitting the method no problem. The issue is that nothings happening, it's not removing anything from the sql database. It's as if I never pressed the button at all.

Comment: And everything looks perfect in the debugger just before you run the query?

Comment: Everything looks ok from what I can see. My hunch is that it has something to do with my page_load method. It's as if the delete command is just being totally ignored .I'm honestly stumped.

Comment: You've proved that it's reaching your deleteData method. Did you confirm that you're getting a valid value back in TextBox4.Text? And that value exactly matches a row value for [PlayerName] in your [Footballer] table?

Comment: @did you try to execute the sql directly to make sure we don't have any problem with constraints or something else? By the way, you should read the value that returns from ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Deleting using an arbitrary string is generally a bad idea..... What if you have two Footballers named "John Smith"?

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere you are actually calling `deleteData()` where is this called from?

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like Textbox4 value is getting overwritten before the Delete, Page_load will get called for each postback including button click event. The flag `bool firstTime = true` doesn't work for the purpose you are trying to achieve. I believe you want to load text box data only when the page loads first time. so you should modify the Page_load event to use [IsPostBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.7.2) property instead of firstTime flag, like below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\App_Data\\Database2.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
    cn = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand command = cn.CreateCommand();

    cn.Open();
    mycount();

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        displayData();             
    }
}
```

This will ensure that, TextBox4 value entered by you in UI won't get overwritten when you click delete button and delete code should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Don't open the connection in `Page_Load` only open it where needed. Also use [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to properly dispose of your resources.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //You should really pull this from your web.config
    string connectionString = "(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\App_Data\\Database2.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";;
    static int count = 1;
    static int max = 2;
    static String sqlQuery = "Select * from Footballer";
    static bool firstTime = true;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        mycount();

        if (firstTime == true)
        {
            displayData();
           firstTime = false;
        }
    }

    protected void mycount()
    {   // count no of els in table
        max = 0;
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.open();
            using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
               cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
               var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               while (reader.Read()) max++;
               reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void displayData()
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.open();
            using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {  
               cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
               var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) reader.Read();
                 TextBox1.Text = "" + reader[0];
                 TextBox2.Text = "" + reader[1];
                 TextBox5.Text = "" + reader[2];
                 TextBox6.Text = "" + reader[3];
                 TextBox7.Text = "" + reader[4];
                 TextBox8.Text = "" + reader[5];
               reader.Close();
         }
       }
    }

    protected void deleteData()
    {
        //Add A break point here to ensure the method is hit
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.open();
            using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {            

              string query = "DELETE from [Footballer] where [PlayerName] = @name";
              cmd.CommandText = query;

              string name = TextBox4.Text;    
              //When stepping through in debug mode, make sure
              //name is what you expect.
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            }
       }
    }
```

Note, I've done all this in the SO editor so I may have missed some closing `}`